# Dependencies in data binding

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

I'd like to add a derived property to flex:

```
 private var a:int;
 private var b:int;
 [Bindable]
 public function get derived():int
 {
     return a+b;
 }
```

However, derived won't update when I change a or b.  Is there a better (faster) way to make derived update than giving a and b setter methods which invalidate it?

Edit: added keyword "get".  This makes more sense now, I hope.

Comment: Oops, I see I forgot "get".  Let me edit this.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not create a property, it creates a method.  Methods cannot be Bindable, only properties.  This approach should work for you:

```
 private var _a:int;
 public function get a():int{
 return _a
 }
 public function set a(value:int):void{
   _a = a; 
   dispatchEvent(new Event('derivedChanged'));
 }
 private var _b:int;
 public function get b():int{
 return _b
 }
 public function set b(value:int):void{
   _b = b; 
   dispatchEvent(new Event('derivedChanged'));
 }

 [Bindable(event="derivedChanged")]
 public function get derived():int
 {
     return a+b;
 }
```

I wrote code n the browser; so there may be minor syntax errors.

Comment: Right, this is exactly my current code.  I wanted to know if I can avoid adding get and set methods for a and b.

Comment: That is not the code you posted. ;)  To trigger binding on a read only property something has to dispatch the binding event.  It doesn't have to be the set methods for a and b, but that is the most logical place.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[Bindable(event="propertyChanged")]` on your derived function.

You should also make your derived function a getter.

I should work because flex uses `PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE` to bind variables, by automatically creating getters and setters and dispatching a `PropertyChangeEvent`. The modification of either a or b will automatically invalidate the result of `derived`.

Answer (score 0):

I felt like this was a common problem, so I wrote some code to help out with it.  You can add what your getter is dependent on in the Bindable metadata.  So:

[Bindable(event="derivedChanged",dependentProperty="a")]
 [Bindable(event="derivedChanged",dependentProperty="b")]
 public function get derived():int
 {
     return a+b;
 }

It's custom code, written to use Parsley's metadata processing, but you could use it without Parsley--it just would be a normal method call and wouldn't look as nice.

Check it out: http://frishy.blogspot.com/2011/06/binding-dependencies.html

-Ryan